# Excel freezes during VBA formula copy down (200,000 rows +)

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I am fairly new to VBA so have one basic code which I am using for quite a lot of my templates and they work perfectly fine but as this one has more than 200,000 rows and the macro freezes or takes 20 min to complete. do you know any ideas or anything how I could make it quicker and not freeze at all please?

macro is here (simply removing trailing space from one column, then dragging all the formulas in first row down to the last row of particular column D)

is there anything I can add to my VBA code to speed it up or will this always be a problem due to large amount of data in the rows? many thanks for your help

```
Sub Fill_formulas_Click() 

Dim LR As Long

Columns("E:E").Select

Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False 

LR = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LR)
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & LR)
Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LR)
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LR)
Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O" & LR)
Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & LR)
Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q" & LR)
Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & LR)
Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & LR)
Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & LR)
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & LR)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to try is to turn off screenupdating and calculation before you start:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


*your_routines*

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
```

If you might have `Event Code` active in your worksheet, you should also turn that off:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

*your_code*

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

Comment: @Rady Let us know what happens.

Comment: hi Ron, so it didn't help and kept crashing again :( so I had to separate it into 3 separate macro buttons. if I don't add the screen update it populates the formulas take 9 min to update (just for 3 columns) if I add it on there it takes 7min 45 so a bit quicker but still looking at good 20 min just to update few columns. oh well thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Rady.  Did you also set calculation to manual?  And does it really crash?  or just take a long time to finish?  Another suggestion would be to do the calculations in VBA (in an array) using native VBA functions.  You have over 2,000,000 calculations there.  Perhaps the calculations can be done more efficiently.

Comment: yes I did, exactly what you said. it works now (ie doesn't crash which is a progress! :) it just takes 10 min to update :)

Comment: my calculations are linking to other 2 spreadsheets to make it better!

Comment: @Rady I don't think you can speed up your process, especially given the number of calculations. If you trigger a **full** recalculation, how long does that take?

Comment: each section takes about 8 min to update or so but it works. seems to be the only way how to do it as we can't streamline the data. Even if I do it manually and try to drag the formula it pretty much does the same so I don't think I can make it better than it is. thank you for your great suggestions! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Ron Rosenfeld provided, simplify the code to the below to reduce the amount of actions taken (screen updating code goes before the `Dim LR as Long` statement):

```
Sub Fill_formulas_Click()

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("E1:E" & LR).Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("A2:C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:C" & LR)
    Range("N2:P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:U" & LR)

End Sub
```